# New to Python. Need help turning a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following code which basically just opens my text file:

```
def vote_dict(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line=line.strip()
            print(line)
```

The text file acts as a voting poll so it has names (x,y,z) that can be repeated multiple times.
example:

```
x
y
x
y
y
z
```

How do I convert this into a dictionary form where it shows key and value?
example:

```
votes={"x": 2, "y": 3, "z": 1}
```

I need help getting to that point. My next step would be to create code that prints the key with the highest value.

Comment: Yes I understand basic dictionaries and opening empty dictionaries. (dict1={})
I'm just not understanding the transition from a text list into a dictionary form.

Comment: You can use the built-in `collections.Counter()`

Comment: I want the "x" to be associated to a value. The value would be how many times "x" was repeated.

Comment: Each key has a value in a dictionary but since my text file only has a list of names does that mean the keys are not associated with a value? I'm not understanding how to create a dictionary that will count the number of times "x" is repeated in my file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use collections.Counter

```
from collections import Counter
def vote_dict(filename):
    temp = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line=line.strip()
            temp.append(line)
    my_dict = Counter(temp)
    print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using simple Python statements, here is a "proof of principle" snippet you can review.

```
vote_dict = {}

def vote(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line=line.strip()
            if line in vote_dict:
                x = int(vote_dict[line])
                x += 1
                vote_dict[line] = x
            else:
                vote_dict[line] = 1

vote("tally.txt")

print(vote_dict)
```

Using your sample data, here was the terminal output.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Votes$ python3 Votes.py 
{'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1}
```

Give that a try if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read().splitlines()` method to make a list of all content in `infile` as element. Then using dict comprehension to add element value of `infile` as dict key and `list.count()` method to count for each value in `infile` as dict value.

```
def vote_dict(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        infile = infile.read().splitlines()
    print(infile)
    return {i: infile.count(i) for i in infile}


print(vote_dict('my_file.txt'))

# output
# ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z']
# {'x': 2, 'y': 3, 'z': 1}
```